# How to separate live and test environments in classic ASP? (please read before untagging jQuery / JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I am writing an application which will have live and test environments in Classic ASP. These use includes a lot. However, because includes are processed before ASP, I can't simply say something like the following:

```
<%
    if <Test Environment Condition> then
%>
        <!-- #include virtual="/myAppTest/start.asp" -->
<%
    else
%>
        <!-- #include virtual="/myApp/start.asp -->
<%
    end if
%>
```

This would basically load BOTH includes into BOTH environments, and throw an error in BOTH environments if there is a malformed function or something similar in ONE environment. The only way I can see, to separate the environments, is to have one virtual directory which simply contains a URL (either /myApp or /myAppTest) and this URL is used in jQuery .load URLs, for example. The only way forward I can see is loading content dynamically via JS.

Another workaround is to have the same virtual directory on 2 servers, one test and one live. However for reasons too complex and possibly too confidential to explain, this option is out the window.

Is the first method, loading content dynamically via JS, the best way or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set  the app up under a different website, not under a vdir.

Comment: Ah, I've vaguely looked into this before, for something else. So have http://mydomain.com/myApp for the public facing application, and http://mydomain.com:<some-port>/myApp for the test application? That sounds like a way forward. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that now.

Comment: Something like that, or have beta.mydomain.com/myapp

Comment: I thought about subdomains - but that's not something under my control (not without requesting it from the Ops team, and that can take a month or so to process). I have access to create virtual directories and manage user accounts and similar things, just not to manage the domain. I'll set up the new website first thing in the morning and let you know how I get on. I'll mark as the answer as soon as I'm able to. Thanks.

Comment: Ya you'd need it support, ideally theyd be more responsive.  Another port should work too, provided it doesn't block it.

Comment: Well I set up the new website, so now I have localhost and localhost:800. On the live server we'll probably have a subdomain pointing to port 800 (or whatever port it ends up being), so it'll be like www.my-domain.com/myApp/ and test.my-domain.com/myApp/. Thanks for the answer, marking as correct now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Server Side Include exactly for the reasons you mentioned.

Instead, you can set single Application level variable in the *global.asa* file and in there define the "environment". For example:

```
Application("Environment") = "Local"
```

Then to "include" proper functions:

```
Server.Execute(Application("Environment") & "_functions.asp")
```

Having **Local_functions.asp** and **Prod_functions.asp** files will then let you include the proper functions based on that application variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but by my understanding `server.execute` does not work in the same way as an include. With an include, all functions defined in the include or in the file calling the include are able to be called from the other file (both before and after the include happens). With `server.execute`, I believe it fires off a new request (I am basing that conclusion purely on how our 'core code' works, not on anything I've looked up; I will do that shortly).